# Select a valid choice. ... is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a simple Django 2.2 application with single model, single model form + custom field and a simple CreateView. I am populating the choices dynamically based on a http call to a outside url. The dropdown is populated fine, but when I try to submit my form I am getting an error:
`Select a valid choice. ... is not one of the available choices` and the form is refreshed with new 3 suggestions in the dropdown.

models.py

```
class GhostUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("User's first name", max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField("User's last name", max_length=100, blank=False)
    ghost_name = models.CharField("User's ghost name", max_length=100, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ghost_name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ghost_names:ghost-update', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

views.py

```
class GhostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'ghost_create.html'
    form_class = GhostUserForm
    success_url = '/'
    # def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     url = "https://donjon.bin.sh/name/rpc-name.fcgi?type=Halfling+Male&n=3"
    #     resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    #     names = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
    #     data['ghost_suggestions'] = names.splitlines()
    #     return data
```

forms.py

```
class GhostUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ghost_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = GhostUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ghost_name'].choices = tuple(get_ghost_names())


def get_ghost_names():
    url = "https://donjon.bin.sh/name/rpc-name.fcgi?type=Halfling+Male&n=10"
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = resp.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
    names = []
    for name in data:
        existing_ghosts = GhostUser.objects.filter(ghost_name=name)
        if existing_ghosts:
            continue
        else:
            print(name.split())
            if len(name.split()) > 1:
                name = name.split()[0]
            names.append((name, name))
    return names[:3]
```

html

```
{% block content %}

<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Create ghost name">
</form>
{% comment %}{{ghost_suggestions}}
<select name="prefer_car_model" id="id_prefer_car_model" required>
                <option value="0" selected disabled> Select ghost name </option>
                {% for obj in ghost_suggestions %}
                <option value="{{ obj }}">{{ obj }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
{% endcomment %}

{% endblock content %}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would appreciate your help on this weird for me issue.

**P.S.** When I add the commented out code from the view and template and render the fold fields one by one, the form submits without errors.

Answer (score 0):

> you did not mention the field name ghost_name in the form.py GhostUserForm class
> change the line

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']  to fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','ghost_name ']
```

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work. Plus I am adding a new custom `ChoiceFiled` to the form before I define the Meta class.